# Is there an Intellij hotkey to quickly apply existing Maven property to a dependency's version?

Tags: intellij-idea, properties, dependencies, pom.xml, hotkeys

In the pom I have a property, for example

```
<guava.version>31.1-jre</guava.version>
```

And I have a dependency I want to add the property to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Is there a hotkey command I can use to quickly select through available properties so I can easily select ${guava.version} and insert it as the version?

Desired end result:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>${guava.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I know I can use ctrl+alt+v to create a property from the dependency version, but I'd also like to be able to later retrieve a property and apply it to a dependency with as little effort as possible.

I've searched, but either I'm no good at googling, or very few have asked this question. I've looked at various lists of key-bindings etc., but can't seem to find anything that addresses my issue.

Comment: There is not such key, but if you type "${}" completion inside will work.

Comment: @y.bedrov Ok.  Strange they'd have it go one way, but not the other.